# Parse error unexpected $end

Tags: php

What does this mean? My page had been working fine until this suddenly appeared after I commented out some code. Here's the code I was working with. It won't let me post this because there isn't enough description so I'm just going to fill up some space.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampp\htdocs\test4\mainpage.php on line 387

<?php 
if($note['type'] == 'list')
{
    $note_type='list';      

    print "<table>";
    while($note_info = mysql_fetch_array( $note_content ))
{
    print "<tr><td>";
    if($note_info['complete'])
       echo "<strike>";
        echo $note_info['body'];
        print "</td>";

    if($note_info['complete']){
        echo "</strike>";           
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='complete_goal' value='".$note_info['note_id']."'></input></td>";
    }   
     print "</tr>";
}


/*  
    print "<dl style=\"float:left\">";  
    while($note_info = mysql_fetch_array( $note_content ))
    {
        if($note_info['complete'])
           echo "<strike>";
    echo "<dt>".$note_info['body']."</dt>";
        if($note_info['complete'])
            echo "</strike>";
    }
    print "</dl>";

    mysql_data_seek($note_content, 0);
    print "<dl style=\"float:right\">"; 
    while($note_info = mysql_fetch_array( $note_content ))
    {
//      if(!$note['complete'])
        echo "<dt><input type='checkbox' name='complete_goal' value='".$note_info['note_id']."'></input></dt>";
    }
    print "</dl>";
}
else
{
    echo $note['body'];
}
*/
?>
```

Comment: You need to paste your code so we can actually see what you've done. I can only assume you've accidentally commented too much and commented out an ending tag somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While commenting out your code, you have also commented the closing brace `}` of the topmost `if($note['type'] == 'list')` condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($note['type'] == 'list')
{
    $note_type='list';      

    echo "<table>";

    while($note_info = mysql_fetch_array( $note_content ))
    {
        print "<tr><td>";

        if($note_info['complete'])
        {
           echo "<strike>";
           echo $note_info['body'];
           echo "</td>";
        }

        if($note_info['complete'])
        {
           echo "</strike>";           
           echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='complete_goal' value='".$note_info['note_id']."'></input></td>";
        }   

        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
```

You should also use an IDE that can detect these errors for you. Give Netbeans a shot.